# Hiding the pins/markers from the map view through method in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

In my `viewDidLoad:` method to show the different locations of number of vehicles I have used some pins/markers/annotations.

What I want to know is that if user selects only one vehicle then how can I hide the other pins/markers.

Is it possible?

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You first need to add an observer to each annotationView to detect when a user selects an annotation. First you must add:

```
static NSString * const GMAP_ANNOTATION_SELECTED = @"gMapAnnotationSelected";
```

to the top of your implementation (right below @implementation). You then must add an observer to each annotationView. This is done by:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)localMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation

//Create your custom annotation called annotationView

[annotationView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selected" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:(void*)("gMapAnnotationSelected")];

return annotationView;
```

Then add the following function to the same file which gets called when the annotationView is selected:

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)localContext {
char *actionCharStr = (char*)localContext;
NSString *action = [NSString stringWithCString:actionCharStr encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];

if ([action isEqualToString:GMAP_ANNOTATION_SELECTED]) {
    BOOL annotationSelected = [[change valueForKey:@"new"] boolValue];

    CustomAnnotationView *customAnnotationView;
    if (annotationSelected) {
        currentAnnotationView = (CustomAnnotationView*)object;
        //Go through each annotation in [yourMap annotations] and remove from map if not equal to [currentAnnotationView annotation]
    } else {
        currentAnnotationView = (CustomAnnotationView*)object;
        //Add the annotations back once the annotation is no longer selected    
    }
}}
```

For more information, look at:
[How to detect AnnotationView selected](http://blog.evandavey.com/2009/07/how-to-detect-when-mkannotation-mkannotationview-is-selected.html)
[MKMapViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKMapViewDelegate)